# Pass parameter from one select function to another using onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two different select option:

**Html:**

```
<select id="lstProveedor" class="form-control select2 select2-accessible" aria-hidden="true"></select>
<select id="lstcuadrilla" class="form-control select2 select2-accessible" aria-hidden="true"></select>
```

**Function:**

```
function getCuadrilla(sender) {
    sender.addClass("changed");
    $("#lstcuadrilla")
        .getJSONCatalog({
            onSuccess: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            url: '/Agenda/GetCuadrillas/' + "?ProveedorID=" + ID,
            valueProperty: "ID",
            textProperty: "NombreComercial"
        });
}

$("#lstProveedor")
    .getJSONCatalog({
        url: '/Agenda/GetProveedores',
        valueProperty: "ID",
        textProperty: "NombreComercial",
        onChange: getCuadrilla()
    });
```

I want to know how to send valueProperty from `$("#lstProveedor")` to `$("#lstcuadrilla")` to get into `url: '/Agenda/GetCuadrillas/' + "?ProveedorID=" + ID,` on change event, how can I do that?

I try to access  it sending into onChange event like:

> onChange: getCuadrilla(valueProperty)

then call into function

```
function getCuadrilla(sender,valueProperty)
```

but it don´t works. Regards

Comment: you could declare valueProperty as a global variable?
then your functions could call `valueProperty: varProperty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First on the `lstProveedor` list add this `onchange` function

```
<select id="lstProveedor" class="form-control select2 select2-accessible" aria-hidden="true" onchange="getCuadrilla(this.value)"></select>
```

In your `getCuadrilla(ID)` have a parameter which will receive this selected ID

You can remove the onchange from the jsoncatalog attached to `lstProveedor`